# Unix Powershell script stops after running SQLPlus command within the script

Tags: powershell, sqlplus, unix

We are trying to create a Unix Powershell (not shell script) script which first runs a SQL to update a couple of tables, psprcsque and psprcsrqst. The function which runs the SQL update gets variables from a Switch which determines what values to use in the SQL. The first time it uses Processing.

`"processing"  { $statusnum = "7"; $timestampcol = "begindttm" }`

Next, a function runs a command is run using Invoke-Expression. The invoke-expression runs another Powershell script which I won't copy here, but it has the location and name of the file. Example /scripts/test.ps1

After the Invoke-Expression command is run, the Powershell script expects a Return code. It then runs through the SQL again with different values.
If Return Code is zero (0).

`"success"     { $statusnum = "9"; $timestampcol = "enddttm" }`

If Return Code is one (1)

`"failed"      { $statusnum = "3"; $timestampcol = "enddttm" }`

This script runs in Windows Powershell with no issues. It runs the first SQL, the runs the Invoke-Expression command, then it runs the SQL again and completes successfully.

In the Unix version of PowerShell, the script stops running after the first SQL command is executed and commits the changes to the database. We see the tables psprcsque and psprcsrsqt are upated correctly. But for some reason, the Powershell script does not continue. It just stops running and does not continue to run the Invoke-Expression command.

We see the output with the following:

1 row updated.

1 row updated.

Commit complete.

But no more output after that and no error message. Any thoughts?

```
#---------------------------------[Parameters]----------------------------------------

[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$DBNAME,
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$ACCESSID,
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$ACCESSPSWD,
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$PRCSINSTANCE,
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$COMMAND
)

#--------------------------------[Variables]------------------------------------------

$PRCSRTNCD    = "0"
$ORACLE_HOME  = $env:ORACLE_HOME
$CONNECT      = "${ACCESSID}/${ACCESSPSWD}@${DBNAME}"
$DEBUG        = $env:DEBUG

#-------------------------------[Initialization]--------------------------------

# Valid values: "Stop", "Inquire", "Continue", "Suspend", "SilentlyContinue"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"

#-------------------------------[Functions]-------------------------------------

function write-debug([String]$message) {
  Write-Host "DEBUG: ${message}" -ForegroundColor Green
}

function write-info([String]$message) {
  Write-Host "INFO: ${message}" -ForegroundColor White
}

function write-error([String]$message) {
  Write-Host "ERROR: ${message}" -ForegroundColor Red
}

function prcsapi([String]$prcsstatus) {
  
  switch ($prcsstatus) {
    "processing"  { $statusnum = "7"; $timestampcol = "begindttm" }
    "success"     { $statusnum = "9"; $timestampcol = "enddttm" }
    "failed"      { $statusnum = "3"; $timestampcol = "enddttm" }
    Default       { $statusnum = "0" }
  }

  $PRCSSQL = @"
set termout on echo on feedback on verify off
connect ${CONNECT}
UPDATE psprcsque
SET    runstatus = ${statusnum}
,      sessionidnum = $pid 
,      lastupddttm = SYSTIMESTAMP
WHERE  prcsinstance = ${PRCSINSTANCE}
;
UPDATE psprcsrqst 
SET    runstatus = ${statusnum}
,      prcsrtncd = ${PRCSRTNCD}
,      continuejob = DECODE(${statusnum},2,1,7,1,9,1,0) 
,      ${timestampcol} = SYSTIMESTAMP
,      lastupddttm = SYSTIMESTAMP
WHERE  prcsinstance = ${PRCSINSTANCE}
;
COMMIT;
exit;
/
"@

  if ($DEBUG -eq "true") {
    write-debug "Params: ${DBNAME} ${ACCESSID} ***** ${PRCSINSTANCE} ${prcsstatus}"  
    write-debug "Status Number: ${statusnum}"
    write-debug "SQL to Run: ${PRCSSQL}"
  }

  $PRCSSQL | . $ORACLE_HOME\bin\sqlplus -S /nolog

}

function execute_command() {
  invoke-expression $COMMAND
  $PRCSRTNCD = $LASTEXITCODE

  if (!($PRCSRTNCD -eq 0)) {
    write-error "Script exited with error code: ${PRCSRTNCD}"
  }
}

#---------------------------------------[Execution]-----------------------------------------

. prcsapi "processing"`
. execute_command`

switch ($PRCSRTNCD) {
  "0" { 
    . prcsapi "success"
    Exit 0 
    }
  "1" { 
    . prcsapi "failed"
    Exit 1
    }
  Default { 
    write-error "Unknown error occured with script"
    . prcsapi "failed"
    Exit 1
    }
}
```